# CircularFloatingActionMenu how to change the color of the FAB?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am using the `CircularFloatingActionMenu` [library](https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu) and the documentation says that the color of the buttons can be changed by replacing the `FAB` code with customized code, how can I replace it?

Edit:
I don't want anyone to do it for me, I want someone to tell me how to do it. I opened the file and I understand what they are doing and what I should change. But I don't know where should I change it. Should I create a class that extends the FAB class provided by the library and try to apply the changes there? how can I use this class then while keeping the other functionality, other than the background color? Or should I copy the code to a new class and change the line that sets the color?

Answer (score 0):

I think you create a FAB like this..

```
FloatingActionButton actionButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
                                        .setContentView(icon)
                                        .build();
```

if this is the case than set the background..something like this

```
 actionButton.setBackGroundResources(R.color.something);
```

or try to change the icon background if it doesn't work.

Comment: I am asking about how to change the class provided by the library, they provide a custom FloatingActionButton class

Comment: Ohhh... let me see it

Comment: I want to change the background color of the Main FAB used in the CircularFloatingActionMenu library, link in the question

Comment: actually that is time consuming.. and no one has enough time to do that for you... i can give you suggestion, Import project in IDE and go through the library code(FABButton) java files and resources and try to understand the flow by the sample given with library.
I thnk that is not a big task if you try it...

Comment: I don't want anyone to do it for me, I want someone to tell me how to do it. I opened the file and I understand what they are doing and what I should change. But I don't know where should I change it. Should I create a class that extends the FAB class provided by the library and try to apply the changes there? how can I use this class then while keeping the other functionality, other than the background color? Or should I copy the code to a new class and change the line that sets the color?

Comment: i mean do some changes and try to run,..do some changes and try to run... so on